# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' when loading a local JQuery file into a HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, httpserver

I am seeing the **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' "** error at line 1 of my local *jquery-3.6.0.min.js* file upon clicking the **'Inspect'** option after loading my HTML file in Chrome.

The highly unexpected thing is, when I move to "sources" on the inspect window, I can see that the *jquery-3.6.0.min.js* file is available. However, its contents are the same as my HTML file! I have attached pictures of examining both index.html and my local JQuery file and you can see that they have the same content.

inspecting *index.html*:
[image]

inspecting *jquery-3.6.0.min.js*:
[image]

Here is how I have loaded the JQuery file into HTML:

```
<html>
                <head>
                <title>Soren</title>
                    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="./js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
                ...

</html>
```

I am quite puzzled by this error because upon reading online matter, I at most expected an *error 404* page to show up as the JQuery file if there were problems loading it, but the last thing I expected was the JQuery file to contain the parent HTML file's content.

Another point to note is that I am launching the HTML file via a server in python such as:

```
class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        """ do_GET() can be tested using curl command
            'curl http://server-ip-address:port'
        """
        file = codecs.open("/home/pi/Burger/index.html", "r", "utf-8")
        html = file.read()

        temp = os.popen("/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp").read()
        self.do_HEAD()
        status = ''
        self.wfile.write(html.format(temp[5:], status).encode("utf-8"))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Online now")
    http_server = HTTPServer((host_name, host_port), MyServer)
    print("Server Starts - %s:%s" % (host_name, host_port))
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Abhinandan

Comment: That error normally occurs when you make an AJAX request to retrieve JSON but the actual response is HTML or XML. It's not a problem with the reference to jQuery itself.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! How do I fix this? I have not worked with servers, html and jquery before. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your path to jquery-3.6.0-min.js is wrong. It's returning the standard 404 HTML page for your site. You just need to correct that path.

Comment: The same error occurred when I specified the entire path as /home/<user>/<folder of index.html>/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js, i.e., when I specify the correct full path of the file... Right now, jquery-3.6.0.min.js is located in the js/ folder which is in the same location as index.html

Comment: In which case, for some reason, the file is not being returned by your webserver and instead you're getting an error page. Unfortunately we can't help you with a configuration problem on the server itself - assuming you're certain that you're using the right file path.

Comment: So you're saying that this might be caused due to a configuration problem on the server? Which means there could be an error in my python code? Also, an important point I forgot to mention is that the server works perfectly when I load the JQuery file using CDN, i.e., a direct link to https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js

Comment: It's ***far*** more likely that you're just giving the wrong path then. Personally I'd just use the CDN version anyway. It will load quicker and will save your server bandwidth

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You've shared the source code of your HTTP server. It gets a GET request and it responds with `index.html`. It **always** responds with `index.html`. It **doesn't** look at the path data in the request and sometimes serves `index.html` and sometimes serves `jquery-3.6.0.min.js`.

Comment: I just tried to put the jquery file in the same directory as index.html and I called it with just its filename. The same error persists, but now I can't even view the jquery file as a source on the inspect mode...

Comment: @Quentin Do you mean I need to change the way the do GET() block opens the html file?

Comment: No. You need to change the GET() block so that it opens the JS file when the browser asks for the JS file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem .
Turns out , I build my app , and had a merge ,
so my main.js file had `<<<<< HEAD >>>>>>` ,
I build my app again anf pushed all the files again ( with no conflidts ) and
My app was up and running again !